# why does AND in parenthesis evaluate differently than without?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence

In C++, `4&1 == 0`, and `1&1 == 1`. However, `4&1 != 1&1` evaluates to `0`, instead of `1`, yet `(4&1) != (1&1)` evaluates to `1` as expected. Why is this?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `!=` and `==` has higher priority than `&`.

Comment: `4&1 = 0` and `1&1 = 1` are not valid expressions.

Comment: @M.M true. i had xor in mind when i asked this. i'll change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relational operator `!=` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than bitwise AND `&`.

Thus the expression

```
4 & 1 != 1 & 1
```

will be parsed as

```
4 & (1 != 1) & 1
```

Comment: The C++ precidence rules are easy.  * binds tighter than +, and everything else just use brackets.  (ok, unary is tighter than binary... usually)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The C++ precedence rules occupy an entire page in the grammar, and the 'solution' you propose is both inconsistent (why not use parentheses for *everything* including `*` and `+`?) and a sure sign of programmer illteracy in the language, at least to me.

Comment: @user20 because brainpower is fungible, and there are far more important things to learn about C++ all the way up to Bjarn's level of literacy.  Nothing wrong with memorizing 100 digits of pi or every operator precidence, it just shouldn't be treated as an important skill.

Comment: In the same way `4&1 == 0` is `4 & (1 == 0)` (`4&0`-> `0`).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I'm pretty sure you omit lot of parents. `x = (f() + (g(42)));` (yes extra parents around `g(42)` as we don't call `42` with `f() + g` :) (similarly to method pointer call)).

Comment: @jarod Those are brackets.  ;)